# Google map don't recognize double

Tags: javascript, google-maps, jsp

I want to create a map from the values I get from my database using [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map).
I'm sure that the values in my jsp are double, but they are not shown in my map (it appears grey).

This is my jsp:

```
<c:if test="${tei.getLatitudine() != null}">
 <span class="elemento">latitudine:</span> 
 <div id="latitudine">${tei.getLatitudine()}</div>  
<br/></c:if>

<c:if test="${tei.getLongitudine() != null}">
 <span class="elemento">longitudine:</span>  
 <div id="longitudine">${tei.getLongitudine()}</div>  
<br/></c:if>
```

I'm trying differents approach:

```
    function initMap() {
  var latitudine = $("#latitudine").val;
  var longitudine = $("#longitudine").val;
  var uluru = {lat: latitudine, lng: longitudine};
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: uluru
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: uluru,
    map: map
  });
}
```

or:

```
function initMap() {
  var latitudine = '${tei.getLatitudine()}';
  var longitudine = '${tei.getLongitudine()}';
  var uluru = {lat: latitudine, lng: longitudine};
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: uluru
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: uluru,
    map: map
  });
}
```

None of the two or other forms I'm using it works.

### Thanks in advance for any help.

**EDIT1:**

The error in my console is:

```
InvalidValueError: setCenter: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number _.kb @ js?key=AIzaSyCIVrSpAqIBx532NG59pY4biIuc5xQGgtA&callback=init‌​Map:37 js?key=AIzaSyCIVrSpAqIBx532NG59pY4biIuc5xQGgtA&callback=init‌​Map:37 

InvalidValueError: setPosition: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number _.kb @ js?key=AIzaSyCIVrSpAqIBx532NG59pY4biIuc5xQGgtA&callback=init‌​Map:37
```

but if I write in my jsp:

```
${tei.getLongitudine().getClass()}
```

it returns class double.

---

**EDIT2:**

If I wrote in my js:

```
var latitudine = ${tei.longitudine}
```

I get this error:

```
message: "initMap is not a function"
name: "InvalidValueError"
stack: "Error
    at new Eb (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=mykey(hidden4privacy)&callback=initMap:41:365)
    at Object._.Fb (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=mykey(hidden4privacy)&callback=initMap:41:475)
    at Og (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=mykey(hidden4privacy)&callback=initMap:96:420)
    at https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=mykey(hidden4privacy)&callback=initMap:131:58
    at Object.google.maps.Load (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=mykey(hidden4privacy)&callback=initMap:21:5)
    at https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=mykey(hidden4privacy)&callback=initMap:130:20
    at https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=mykey(hidden4privacy)&callback=initMap:131:73"
```

Comment: any console error ? this is happening in browser so you must get some kind of exception.

Comment: it says:
InvalidValueError: setCenter: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number
_.kb @ js?key=AIzaSyCIVrSpAqIBx532NG59pY4biIuc5xQGgtA&callback=initMap:37
js?key=AIzaSyCIVrSpAqIBx532NG59pY4biIuc5xQGgtA&callback=initMap:37 InvalidValueError: setPosition: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number
_.kb @ js?key=AIzaSyCIVrSpAqIBx532NG59pY4biIuc5xQGgtA&callback=initMap:37
but if I use ${tei.getLongitudine().getClass()} it stamp class double

Comment: If I wrote ${tei.getLongitudine()} without '' the error that appear is:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Comment: var latitudine = ${tei.longitudine} try it please. getLongitudine() method called longitudine in EL.

Comment: see my second edit

Comment: I tried and works well.

Comment: var a = ${requestScope.lng.longitudine}; var a = ${sessionScope.lng.longitudine};

Comment: I solved it writing the code inside the jsp and after the map div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have model like this;

```
public class MyModel{

private double longitudine;

public double getLongitudine() {
    return longitudine;
}

public void setLongitudine(double longitudine) {
    this.longitudine = longitudine;
}
}
```

and put request or session your model

```
MyModel d = new MyModel();

d.setLongitudine(24);
session.setAttribute("lng",d); // or
// request.setAttribute("lng",d);
```

then you can access properties using EL in JS like this.

```
function myFunction() {
var a = ${sessionScope.lng.longitudine}; /*or*/
/* var a = ${requestScope.lng.longitudine}; */
var b = a + 5;
console.log(b);
}
```

Comment: I used requestScope writing the script directly inside jsp thank you